# Saving a copy to a disk with the appropriate volume name

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

i have a script that creates a copy of MS SQL databases for me. I would like the script not to have a statically entered place where the data will be stored and make a copy to the disk whose volume name is "xxx"

```
$CelNaDysku = 'X:\SQL'
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "BACKUP DATABASE ""$($_.Name)"" TO DISK = '$CelNaDysku\$($_.Name)\$($_.Name)-$CzasTeraz.bak'" -ServerInstance $Instancja -QueryTimeout $TimeOut
```

Comment: `$_` is undefined outside of a pipeline's script block, where it represents the current input object.. What do you expect it to contain? Isn't it safer to consistently use `'...'` inside the T-SQL string? What, specifically, doesn't work?

Comment: Is the volume label really `xxx`? Use `Get-Volume` to obtain drive letters.

Comment: I create backups, and I want to avoid the situation that the backup will not be on this disk as it should. That's why I thought that I would create a volume name, eg "xxx" and the script would find the drive letter that is assigned to the volume name.